# Lenovo u410 Resolution Upgrade Problems and Questions

Tags: display, resolution, lcd, laptop-repair, laptop-display

I'm an IT Pro, so I'm not a complete noob, but I will say that dealing with specific differences in notebook video cables is something new to me.

I got a u410 for an absolute steal and it's perfect for me except for the resolution.  I purchased a new panel (1600x900 Matte - https://www.laptopscreen.com/English/section/search/index.php?section=products&model=M14X&brand=Alienware) and it fits perfectly, but it appears to be missing a whole set of vertical lines.  That's the best way I can think of to describe it.  Based on what I've read, this is due to the cable itself - the connector fits just like a standard 40 pin, but it's definitely missing something.  On one of about 10 attempts I got the color to display perfectly, but it was still clearly missing vertical lines (images ok, text almost unreadable).  If you've dealt with bad display connections you know what I'm talking about.

My question is: What can I do?  Can I get a different cable and fix the issue or am I stuck at 1366x768? I'm willing to go to just about any lengths to get a higher res panel working in here (it was that good of a deal).

Answer (score 2):

It is almost impossible to upgrade the resolution. I tried it myself.
The mainboard (Quanta LZ8) has only single channel support for this unique LVDS connector. You need dual channel support for higher resolutions than 1366x768 (like 1600x900).

Source: 
http://kythuatphancung.vn/uploads/download/1b22d_Quanta_LZ8_-_REV_1A_-_Lenovo_IdeaPad_U410.pdf (pages: 7 and 22)

Name of the LVDS-Cable: dd0lz8lc030